# If table 1 and 2 or 3 have the same IDs show the name

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables:

- Campaign
- Customer
- Office

As in the **Campaign** table the customer_id the same is as ID in the **Customer** table,
then he must show the customer_name also in Customer table.

Now he is showing the customer id with: `$row->customer_id`

I now have the following

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM campaign ORDER BY campaign_id"))
{
    // display records if there are records to display
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        // display records in a table
        echo "<table>";

        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            // set up a row for each record
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->campaign_name . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->customer_id . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->office_id . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not incredibly clear what you're asking, but maybe try this query?

```
SELECT c.*, cust.* FROM campaign c, customer cust WHERE c.customer_id=cust.customer_id ORDER BY c.campaign_id
```

Using explicit (instead of implicit) JOINs, this query can be written as this:

```
SELECT c.*, cust.* FROM campaign c JOIN customers cust ON c.customer_id=cust.customer_id
```

As a note, I usually prefer to call out column names explicitly in queries, but since you didn't post your schema, I wasn't sure the names of your columns. Possibly something like this:

```
SELECT c.campaign_name, cust.customer_id FROM campaign c JOIN customers cust ON c.customer_id=cust.customer_id
```

Comment: . . I boycott upvoting answers that use implicit join syntax.  You should learn to use explicit `join`s all the time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Fair. However I found that the implicit syntax is a bit easier for SQL beginners to wrap their heads around (instead of blindly copying and pasting code they don't understand). I will edit to include an explicit join.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it with: `SELECT camp.*, cust.*, offi.* FROM campaign camp, customer cust, office offi WHERE camp.customer_id=cust.customer_id AND camp.customer_id=offi.office_id ORDER BY camp.date_changed DESC`